Does VScode load text-based log files completely into memory when opening over SMB shares?
In the future, I need to access log files over SMB tunneled through OpenVPN and those log files might be pretty large. Downloading all of the log files content to show it might take a long time. I wasn't able to find anything regarding how VScode loads text files, if it always reads the entire file into memory or uses an approach like memory-mapped files. In the first case things would be as slow as downloading the whole file, while in the latter case one would be far sooner able to see file content.
Regarding large local files, my impression is that VScode loads the entire file into memory, because loading large failesd with multiple hundreds of MiB takes a long time, consumes a lot of memory, I can see lots reads on the disk, in ProcMon etc. I guess it's the same over SMB then.
So, does anyone know already how VScode behaves over SMB? In theory it might have some optimization, assuming slow network connections ro stuff.
Thanks!
